# How to get signed in user identity in a website after signing in with another website using ACS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, wif, claims-based-identity, azure-acs

I have one website which is configured to use Azure ACS. When the user signs to this website, how will I get the user identity when he visits another one of my website so that the user will not need to choose and sign in to his identity provider in ACS? Is there a way to get the user identity from ACS across multiple websites so that once a user logs in to one of my websites he will be recognized as a logged in user when he visits other ACS configured websites? BTW Im using all 4 social networking sites in azure ACS as identity providers.

Comment: there is no out-of-the-box way to achieve that. But given you are in-control of all sites, there is something you could do. I'm trying to figure out how to put it in a single answer though. Because it is not as straight forward as I wish it is.

Comment: Could you provide me with links to relevant resources? Would I be on the right track though if I implement a hybrid approach by having claim-based and role based authentication? I would just make my own identity provider that functions as the user repository for all of the websites and have the websites check if the user is logged in to the IP? But im not sure if this would work or if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: One stupid approach i could think of is that once you have the user authenticated via ACS, pass back to your website some encrypted token,  which carries the identity of the user. Pass around this token whenever you hop from one site to another. Whenever you find at your server side the token sent to be null or invalid, assume the user is not logged in. If all the websites are under the same domain, you could use cookie to pass around the token easily. Didn't think much about the pros and cons, but seems legit.

Answer (score 1):

Each website is different from ACS perspective, so the tokens it will issue are also different. SSO however, happens at the IdP level:

1. User logs in with Google (as an example) on WebSite 1.
2. User goes to WebSite2, (with the same browser instance), WebSite2 redirects to ACS, ACS redirects to Google
3. User is already authenticated with Google, comes back to ACS
4. ACS issues a token (for WebSite2) and returns to WebSite2

ACS doesn't keep sessions with user so they will be forced to do the entire transaction at least once.

What could happen is that if you have 4 social IdP (Google, Live, FB, Yahoo presumably), in step 2, ACS will prompt the user for the IdP to use.

To avoid this, you have to send the login request to ACS with the **whr** parameter. You would have to remember which one was used by your user and instruct ACS to use that. With whr, there's no IdP prompt.

Comment: How to redirect to a specific IdP (i.e O365) in ACS when there are +1. Which whr parameter to use?

Comment: I would not recommend using ACS anymore as it is deprecated.